# morphological processing FIT/MISS

Tags: image-processing

I'm learning image processing and came accross the **FIT AND HIT** concept using structurial element. I'm confused in regards to how it works.

My understanding is that when the highlighted pixel in S.E matches the pixel in the image it is a HIT?

And for a FIT  all the pixels in the SE should overlap  specific parts of the image?

please let  me know if i am on the  right track

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with any *Fit and Hit* algorithm used in mathematical morphology. Possibly you mean *Hit or Miss*.

**Hit or Miss** (also Hit and Miss) transform uses *composite structuring element* (CSE). The common structuring element contains just foreground pixels, but CSE contains both foreground (one) and background (zero) pixels. Hit or Miss transform works like this: *Does the first set fit the foreground while, simultaneously, the second set misses it (i.e. fits the background)? If yes, include the origin into the result.* It means that foreground of the CSE must fit the image (pixels with value 1) and at the same time background of the CSE must fit the background of the image (pixels with value 0).

You can try Hit or Miss for yourself by [running this applet](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hitandmissdemo.htm). There's 3x3 CSE and you can select which pixels represent foreground and background (by selecting Any you set no restriction). The origin is in the middle of the CSE. There's also option to load another image or your own image by pasting URL (but keep in mind that only binary images will work).

Hit or Miss is generally used to find specific configurations of
pixels, such as isolated pixels or endpoints, and also for thinning and skeletonizing. For more info, read some related material, e.g. [Hit-and-Miss Transform](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hitmiss.htm) or [Mathematical Morphology](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ibv/reader/chapter6.pdf).